# Creating a directory in Internal memory (Root Folder)

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Directory in the internal memory of the device...

I have done like this ...

```
File testDir = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory(),"Sample");
    testDir.mkdir();
```

But i cant see a folder created in the file explorer of DDMS when i run it in the emulator. I have also added

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to the manifest file. Is anything else to be added... Is this the right way? If no plz suggest me the correct procedure.

Comment: hey I want the same thing as you. What was the solution to make a folder in root folder. to store files. what was the trick ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot write to the root of internal storage from an SDK application.

Comment: My application is creating a folder in SDCard. But some devices may not have SD.So, i want to create a folder in internal memory if SD card is not present. How can i store my files in internal memory...? Plz advice

Comment: @Rahul Varma: Use `getFilesDir()` to get a `File` object pointing to a place on internal flash where your application can store files.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply... Your tutorials and suggesstions are of great help for Newbies like me... If possible please provide any samples of accessing and modifying content from internal memory.

Comment: @Rahul Varma: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Files/ReadWrite

Comment: Then how WhatsApp creates folder in internal root nammed "WhatsApp"?

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi: WhatsApp does not do that. You are confusing what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) with what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility to write in any folder you want in the internal sotrage would be to have a rooted phone. Moreover, it is a very **bad** idea to do so. Why do you want to do that ?

EDIT : Ok, read your comment above. I'd then advise you to read the [storage doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) on Android official site, which will tell you how to save your file in the internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getDir() function for opening(if exists) or creating directory.